# Postgres how to transfer all enums from foreign server

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper

I have two databases that I want to be able to transfer data between, so I want to import a large schema from one database to the other, where there is allot of enums. So I ran into the problem descripted here [SQL: error when creating a foreign table that has an enum column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332805/sql-error-when-creating-a-foreign-table-that-has-an-enum-column).

So I though I would like to something like "pg_dump enum" to get the enums and transfer them to the other database.
But I can't such a command. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can export the definitions with a query like this:

```
SELECT format(
          'CREATE TYPE %s AS ENUM (%s);',
          enumtypid::regtype,
          string_agg(quote_literal(enumlabel), ', ')
       )
FROM pg_enum
GROUP BY enumtypid;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer and how you are helping the community.